# How does pytest "know" where to import code from?

Tags: python, pytest

This thread is a follow-up to an unsuccessful attempt to resolve the issue on Reddit, which can be seen in its entirety [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/18ugodb/confused_about_how_pytest_knows_where_to_import/), though I will of course replicate the essential information here as well, starting with the OP:

I am following along with `Python Testing with pytest` and am utterly baffled as to how pytest finds a certain class in the example I am working with. All of the code is here in a .zip file:

https://pragprog.com/titles/bopytest2/python-testing-with-pytest-second-edition/

So `code/ch2/test_card.py` starts with `from cards import Card`. Class `Card` is defined in `cards_proj/src/cards/api.py`. I can confirm that removing `code/cards_proj/pyproject.toml` and `code/pytest.init` (which is just comments anyway), first severally, then jointly, did not prevent the successful run of the tests. pytest would not let me just print out `sys.path` in or out of any of the test functions, so I did something I am not terribly proud of instead:

```
from cards import Card
import sys

def test_field_access():
    with open('path.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(p + '\n' for p in sys.path)

    c = Card("something", "brian", "todo", 123)
    assert c.summary == "something"
    assert c.owner == "brian"
    assert c.state == "todo"
    assert c.id == 123

# ...remainder omitted
```

The result in `path.txt` did nothing to clarify matters:

```
/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/code/ch2
/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv/bin
/usr/lib/python310.zip
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

There was only one serious attempt to help me, which did not go anywhere. Briefly:

I was asked about the contents of `src/__init__.py`, which did not exist, though I was able to divulge the contents of `code/cards_proj/src/cards/__init__.py`:

```
"""Top-level package for cards."""

__version__ = "1.0.0"

from .api import *  # noqa
from .cli import app  # noqa
```

I was encouraged to upload the code to GitHub. After being unsure whether I should due to copyright I figured it probably wouldn't be too bad; after all, I found the first edition code from a third party without a fuss being made about it. Because multiple files are obviously involved, I can't replicate everything easily in a Stack Overflow thread; however, here is a link to the [initial commit](https://github.com/readyready15728/python-testing-with-pytest/commit/20a9f261cdb481c6ad6941d45a76af73b0a87e05) which will not change even if I do more commits.

I ran two commands to shed some light on the directory structure. Here is the output of `find -mindepth 1 -type d | sort` executed in `code/`:

```
./cards_proj
./cards_proj/src
./cards_proj/src/cards
./ch1
./ch10
./ch11
./ch11/cards_proj
./ch11/cards_proj/.github
./ch11/cards_proj/.github/workflows
./ch11/cards_proj/src
./ch11/cards_proj/src/cards
./ch11/cards_proj/tests
./ch11/cards_proj/tests/api
./ch11/cards_proj/tests/cli
./ch12
./ch12/app
./ch12/app/src
./ch12/app/tests
./ch12/script
./ch12/script_funcs
./ch12/script_importable
./ch12/script_src
./ch12/script_src/src
./ch12/script_src/tests
./ch13
./ch13/cards_proj
./ch13/cards_proj/src
./ch13/cards_proj/src/cards
./ch13/cards_proj/tests
./ch13/cards_proj/tests/api
./ch13/cards_proj/tests/cli
./ch14
./ch14/random
./ch15
./ch15/just_markers
./ch15/local
./ch15/pytest_skip_slow
./ch15/pytest_skip_slow/examples
./ch15/pytest_skip_slow_final
./ch15/pytest_skip_slow_final/examples
./ch15/pytest_skip_slow_final/tests
./ch16
./ch1/.backup
./ch1/__pycache__
./ch2
./ch2/.backup
./ch2/__pycache__
./ch2/.pytest_cache
./ch2/.pytest_cache/v
./ch2/.pytest_cache/v/cache
./ch3
./ch3/a
./ch3/b
./ch3/c
./ch3/d
./ch4
./ch5
./ch6
./ch6/bad
./ch6/builtins
./ch6/combined
./ch6/multiple
./ch6/reg
./ch6/slow
./ch6/smoke
./ch6/strict
./ch6/tests
./ch7
./ch8
./ch8/alt
./ch8/dup
./ch8/dup/tests_no_init
./ch8/dup/tests_no_init/api
./ch8/dup/tests_no_init/cli
./ch8/dup/tests_with_init
./ch8/dup/tests_with_init/api
./ch8/dup/tests_with_init/cli
./ch8/project
./ch8/project/tests
./ch8/project/tests/api
./ch8/project/tests/cli
./ch9
./ch9/some_code
./exercises
./exercises/ch10
./exercises/ch11
./exercises/ch11/src
./exercises/ch12
./exercises/ch2
./exercises/ch5
./exercises/ch6
./exercises/ch8
./exercises/ch8/tests
./exercises/ch8/tests/a
./exercises/ch8/tests/b
./.pytest_cache
./.pytest_cache/v
./.pytest_cache/v/cache
```

I was also asked to carry out `tree` in the directory `ch2`, which I obliged specifically by running `tree -a`:

```
├── .backup
│   └── test_card.py~
├── path.txt
├── __pycache__
│   └── test_card.cpython-310-pytest-7.4.3.pyc
├── .pytest_cache
│   ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── README.md
│   └── v
│       └── cache
│           ├── nodeids
│           └── stepwise
├── test_alt_fail.py
├── test_card_fail.py
├── test_card.py
├── test_classes.py
├── test_exceptions.py
├── test_experiment.py
├── test_helper.py
└── test_structure.py
```

`.backup/` and `path.txt` are the results of my involvement. It should be clear from the output of the two commands that pytest "knows" to climb to a higher level in the file system, then climb down into `cards_proj/src/` to import the code. The other Reddit user suggested I wasn't just running pytest in the `ch2/` subdirectory. I made certain:

[image: I was in fact in ch2 at time]

(Text description to accompany image: the terminal shows the working directory as `ch2/`)

I also looked at some cached files but found no leads there.

It was then suggested: "Somehow I'm [sure] the root of the project is being added to your path and so you're able to import the modules that are exported at the root of the project". I then printed out the output of `set -L` (I'm using fish), with the sole exception of `history`, both for brevity and for privacy reasons:

```
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/lib/stublibs'  '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/lib/ocaml/stublibs'  '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/lib/ocaml'
CLUTTER_BACKEND x11
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE ibus
CMD_DURATION 0
COLORTERM truecolor
COLUMNS 226
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
DESKTOP_SESSION xubuntu
DISPLAY :0.0
FISH_VERSION 3.3.1
GPG_AGENT_INFO /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
GTK3_MODULES xapp-gtk3-module
GTK_IM_MODULE ibus
GTK_MODULES gail:atk-bridge
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING 0
HOME /home/readyready15728
IFS \n\ \t
LANG en_US.UTF-8
LINES 53
LOGNAME readyready15728
LS_COLORS 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
MANPATH ''  '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/man'
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH /home/readyready15728/.opam/default/lib/toplevel
OMF_CONFIG /home/readyready15728/.config/omf
OMF_INVALID_ARG 3
OMF_MISSING_ARG 1
OMF_PATH /home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf
OMF_UNKNOWN_ERR 4
OMF_UNKNOWN_OPT 2
OPAM_SWITCH_PREFIX /home/readyready15728/.opam/default
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN /run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
PANEL_GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS 0
PATH '/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/nios2eds/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus/bin'  '/usr/local/sbin'  '/usr/local/bin'  '/usr/sbin'  '/usr/bin'  '/sbin'  '/bin'  '/usr/games'  '/usr/local/games'  '/snap/bin'
PWD /home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/code/ch2
QT_ACCESSIBILITY 1
QT_IM_MODULE ibus
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME gtk2
SESSION_MANAGER local/stygies-viii:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1334,unix/stygies-viii:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1334
SHELL /usr/bin/fish
SHLVL 2
SSH_AGENT_PID 1454
SSH_AUTH_SOCK /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
TERM xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM tmux
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION 3.2a
TMUX /tmp/tmux-1000/default,86921,0
TMUX_PANE '%7'
TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH /home/readyready15728/.tmux/plugins/
USER readyready15728
VIRTUAL_ENV /home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv
VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT '(venv) '
VTE_VERSION 6800
WINDOWID 71303171
XAUTHORITY /home/readyready15728/.Xauthority
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP XFCE
XDG_DATA_DIRS /usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/home/readyready15728/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
XDG_MENU_PREFIX xfce-
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR /run/user/1000
XDG_SEAT seat0
XDG_SEAT_PATH /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_CLASS user
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP XFCE
XDG_SESSION_ID 3
XDG_SESSION_PATH /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session3
XDG_SESSION_TYPE x11
XDG_VTNR 1
XMODIFIERS @im=ibus
_ set
_OLD_FISH_PROMPT_OVERRIDE /home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH '/home/readyready15728/.opam/default/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/nios2eds/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus/bin'  '/usr/local/sbin'  '/usr/local/bin'  '/usr/sbin'  '/usr/bin'  '/sbin'  '/bin'  '/usr/games'  '/usr/local/games'  '/snap/bin'
__fish_active_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings
__fish_added_user_paths
__fish_bin_dir /usr/bin
__fish_cd_direction prev
__fish_config_dir /home/readyready15728/.config/fish
__fish_config_interactive_done
__fish_data_dir /usr/share/fish
__fish_help_dir /usr/share/doc/fish
__fish_initialized 3100
__fish_last_bind_mode default
__fish_locale_vars 'LANG'  'LC_ALL'  'LC_COLLATE'  'LC_CTYPE'  'LC_MESSAGES'  'LC_MONETARY'  'LC_NUMERIC'  'LC_TIME'
__fish_ls_color_opt --color=auto
__fish_ls_command ls
__fish_sysconf_dir /etc/fish
__fish_user_data_dir /home/readyready15728/.local/share/fish
dirprev '/media/readyready15728/LIBERET NOS DEUS MACHINARIUS AB IGNORANTIA/Pictures'  '/home/readyready15728'  '/home/readyready15728/src/vim'  '/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest'  '/home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/code'
fish_bind_mode default
fish_color_autosuggestion '555'  'brblack'
fish_color_cancel -r
fish_color_command 005fd7
fish_color_comment 990000
fish_color_cwd green
fish_color_cwd_root red
fish_color_end 009900
fish_color_error ff0000
fish_color_escape 00a6b2
fish_color_history_current --bold
fish_color_host normal
fish_color_host_remote yellow
fish_color_match --background=brblue
fish_color_normal normal
fish_color_operator 00a6b2
fish_color_param 00afff
fish_color_quote 999900
fish_color_redirection 00afff
fish_color_search_match 'bryellow'  '--background=brblack'
fish_color_selection 'white'  '--bold'  '--background=brblack'
fish_color_status red
fish_color_user brgreen
fish_color_valid_path --underline
fish_complete_path '/home/readyready15728/.config/fish/completions'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/completions'  '/etc/fish/completions'  '/usr/share/xubuntu/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/usr/share/xfce4/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/usr/share/fish/vendor_completions.d'  '/usr/share/fish/completions'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/fish/generated_completions'
fish_function_path '/home/readyready15728/.config/fish/functions'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/compat'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/core'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/index'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/packages'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/themes'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/bundle'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/util'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/repo'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions/cli'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/fish-spec/functions'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf/functions'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/lib'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/lib/git'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/themes/bobthefish'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/themes/bobthefish/functions'  '/etc/fish/functions'  '/usr/share/xubuntu/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/usr/share/xfce4/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/home/readyready15728/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/usr/share/fish/vendor_functions.d'  '/usr/share/fish/functions'
fish_greeting Welcome\ to\ fish,\ the\ friendly\ interactive\ shell\nType\ `help`\ for\ instructions\ on\ how\ to\ use\ fish
fish_handle_reflow 0
fish_key_bindings fish_default_key_bindings
fish_kill_signal 0
fish_killring 'scrapers/'  'misc/docker-deep-dive-2023/'  's2'  'vim'  'git '  'clean'  'pushd ~/'
fish_pager_color_completion
fish_pager_color_description 'B3A06D'  'yellow'
fish_pager_color_prefix 'white'  '--bold'  '--underline'
fish_pager_color_progress 'brwhite'  '--background=cyan'
fish_pid 87527
fish_user_paths '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/nios2eds/bin'  '/home/readyready15728/altera/13.0sp1/quartus/bin'
hostname stygies-viii
last_pid 1358117
omf_init_path /home/readyready15728/.local/share/omf/pkg/omf
pipestatus 2
status 2
status_generation 32
umask 0002
version 3.3.1
```

You'll notice I made sure to reactivate my venv to ensure that the conditions are the same but, even so, `PYTHONPATH` is not set and nothing else I saw looks like a lead. Like I said, how does pytest "know" where to import the code being tested from?

Comment: Although there's a lot here, I get the sense key information is missing. However, this seems to explain how it could https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557

Comment: I don't know what was a better way to show with 100% certainty the CWD @N1ngu

Comment: That seems helpful @Grismar

Comment: Can you change `test_field_access` to perform `import cards` and record the value of `cards.__path__`, in addition to `sys.path`?

Comment: Note that just running the unit tests from a pretty common IDE like PyCharm doesn't work without setting up additional environment variables. Running `test_card.py` with `python.exe C:\temp\code\ch2\test_card.py` fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cards'`, as you seem to expect. So, more information is needed about the environment in which this surprisingly runs. Running the same with `PYTHONPATH=C:\temp\code\cards_proj\src` added to the environment does make it run - so that still seems to be the obvious answer.

Comment: The text of the terminal should be enough. It's not like people will think you faked it because... you know, you are asking for help.

Comment: I don't think anyone thinks might have I faked it. I'm more worried about people thinking I dropped the ball. @N1ngu

Comment: whatever, just drop the images

Comment: anyway, where is the module imported from? I mean, what's the output for `python -c 'import cards; print(cards.__file__)'`?

Comment: @user2357112 Now we're really getting somewhere. The result is /home/readyready15728/programming/python/python-testing-with-pytest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cards. That means pytest wasn't doing the voodoo I thought it was the whole time.

Comment: Just answered @N1ngu

Comment: So, at some point in time you did run `pip install ./cards_proj` in your virtualenv. Thanks to the presence of a proper `pyproject.toml` file, `cards_proj/src/cards` was packaged and moved to your venv. Now python can import that. Also pytest, of course ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah and I'm going to put that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 12, I did `pip install ./cards_proj` in the appropriate location and had forgotten. The sample Cards application truly was in the venv path.